# Автоматическое перелистывание меню Fullpage.js при скролле секций?

Tags: javascript, swiper, fullpage, fullpage.js

Всем привет!
Мне нужно листать мое навигационное меню при переходе на секции.
То есть если я нахожусь на 7 секции менюшка должна сама перелистываться, без нажатия на стрелку.
Я не знаю, есть ли это в fullpage.js, но мне очень нужно это сделать.
Я пытался с помощью swiper slider, но с ним работают только стрелки(если нажимаю на них, то появляются новые названия секций), но при скролле он не листается... Помогите!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Сделал с помощью встроенного метода в fullpage.js "onLeave". Сделал условие, если нахожусь на определенном слайде, то перелистывать слайдер при помощи метода swiper slideNext()

код

```
 switch (origin.index) {

  case 1:
    mySwiper.slideNext()
    break
  }
```